# POST Request: How to read req.body from form

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, ejs

I have used POSTMAN to understand how API requests work, but now I don't know how to integrate that with my frontend. **How do I get data from the request body?**

I have the following in my `index.ejs` file:

```
<form action="/items" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" id="user-input" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Add an item to shopping list" name="input">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-group-sm" id="add-button" type="submit">ADD</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

and I need to get what the user inputs in the input box above. This is what I have in my `app.js` file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/items', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    if(items.includes(req.body.input)){
        console.log("Item already exists!");
    } else {
        items.push(req.body.input);
        console.log("Item added");
        console.log(items);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

The POST request is working-ish, but the added item is `undefined` and if I remove `.input` from `req.body` the item is `[object Object]`.

What am I doing wrong, or what should I do differently?

Comment: When the data is sent by the form, it is not sent as JSON, but as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try to use `bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })` (either in place of `bodyParser.json()`, or along with it if you still want to accept JSON as well)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype

Comment: @blex: got it! it worked now, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());